# VBA ADO single command with Insert and Select query

Tags: vba, t-sql, sql-server-2012, adodb

I'm trying to execute the following SQL statement in an Excel Macro, but it fails to return a valid recordset. I suspect that having both an `INSERT` and a `SELECT` in the same statement is the culprit.

strSQL :

```
DECLARE @PurchOrdersTmpXl_A147 Table( SrNo INT, PONum VARCHAR(255)); 

INSERT INTO @PurchOrdersTmpXl_A147 (SrNo, PONum) 
    VALUES (1, 'PO0001968'), 
           (2, 'PO0000260'); 

SELECT
    XLPO.SrNo [PO Order], 
    POOrigLine.PURCHID  [Orig PO],  
    POOrigLine.ITEMID   [Orig Item], 
    POOrigLine.Name     [Orig Txt]
FROM 
    dbo.PURCHLINE  POOrigLine 
        INNER JOIN @PurchOrdersTmpXl_A147 [XLPO] 
            ON POOrigLine.PurchID = XLPO.PONum 
WHERE 
    POOrigLine.PurchStatus != 4
```

VBA Code

```
Set ADOConn = New ADODB.Connection
ADOConn.connectionString = strConnect
ADOConn.Open

Set ADOcmd = New ADODB.Command
ADOcmd.ActiveConnection = ADOConn
ADOcmd.CommandText = strSQL

Set ADOrs = ADOcmd.Execute
Debug.Print ADOrs.RecordCount // Gives error "Operation Not Allowed when object is closed"
```

Any help?

Thanks in advance.

***Note 1:***
I can confirm that this error is because I'm trying to execute an `Insert` query and a `SELECT` query in the same command string.

There are no errors if I use a temp table instead of the above table variable and split the command execution (execute the `CREATE` and `INSERT` first and then execute the `SELECT`).
However, as my temp table will never hold more than 20 records, I figure table variables would be more performance effective.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Set ADOrs = New ADODB.Recordset
With ADOrs
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    Call .Open(strSQL, ADOConn, , , adCmdText)
    If Not (.BOF And .EOF) Then Debug.Print .RecordCount
End With
```

In this case, the `Command` object is not needed; you only need the `Recordset` object.

Answer (score 0):

Is it an option to turn this SQL into a stored procedure? You might have more luck that way as you can hide the other recordsets (which might be why it's closed)

Also is this the whole piece of SQL Code? Why not just select directly from the table? If you want to run this for a set of SrNo/PONum, then there is even more reason to run as a stored proc as you can pass table valued parameters.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx

Here is an example stored proc that works for one set. See the link above for using many sets.

```
CREATE PROC p_Stuff 
@SrNo INt, @PONum VARCHAR(255)
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @PurchOrdersTmpXl_A147 Table( SrNo INT, PONum VARCHAR(255)); 

INSERT INTO @PurchOrdersTmpXl_A147 (SrNo, PONum) 
    VALUES (@SrNo, @PONum); 

SELECT
    XLPO.SrNo [PO Order], 
    POOrigLine.PURCHID  [Orig PO],  
    POOrigLine.ITEMID   [Orig Item], 
    POOrigLine.Name     [Orig Txt]
FROM 
    dbo.PURCHLINE  POOrigLine 
        INNER JOIN @PurchOrdersTmpXl_A147 [XLPO] 
            ON POOrigLine.PurchID = XLPO.PONum 
WHERE 
    POOrigLine.PurchStatus != 4
```

and then execute as a stored procedure

```
EXEC p_Stuff 1, 'PO0001968'
```

Comment: Ahh.. the catch here is that the table variable will have more than one records (varies between 1 and 20, not a hard limit). For brevity, I only showed one (original question now amended). Is it possible to send multiple values to stored procedures?

Comment: Yes those are the table valued parameters I referred to. Check the link in the post.